# Unable to import libraries to eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, androidplot

When I try to use libraries they all seem empty to me (when I try to import them I can only see 'empty' packages). I tried both: drag-drop libraries to \libs and importing them. I don't know what is causing this problem...

I'm trying to import **androidplot** libraries, I'm not finding this particular issue on their boards so maybe I'm doing something wrong?!

[image: view on libraries]

EDIT

[image: file in libraries folder]

Comment: try copying you jar to libs folder of your project

Comment: I've put it in libs folder already. And it didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're importing the  androidplot sources jar which wont work because its full of .java files instead of the expected .class files. [Use the library jar instead](https://androidplot.jira.com/builds/artifact/ANDROIDPLOT-TRUNK/RELEASE/build-132/Jars/androidplot-core-0.5.2.jar).

Answer (score 0):

You should put them in your "libs" folder below, among with the others such as "android-support-v4", not with the Android the dependencies.

Comment: But I said I tried to drag-drop libraries to \libs, and it didn't work.

Comment: What is not working? You don't succeed to copy the libraries into the libs folder or the "import" in the code are not working?

Comment: I copied it to libs folder but they all seem to be empty packages. When I try to import them within `Activity` I can choose `import com.androidplot.xy*;` but there's nothing within package.

Answer (score 0):

depending on the ADT version that you use, you may want to start reading [here](http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/projects-cmdline.html#ReferencingLibraryProject)

Note that lib usages is no longer simple process of copying jars to a folder and building. The library project may need to be in eclipse and build as 'library' then referred to as a dependency in the specific idiom mentioned above in link.

Comment: Your link leads to managing projects from command line, which I never did, and it would be very difficult for me to comprehend. My problem is really a matter of (seemingly) empty libraries - as seen on screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the below steps .this might help you:

1-> Right Click on Your Project

2-> Click on Build Path

3->  Select Configure Build Path

4-> Select Add External JAR

5-> Locate Jar file in your System and add

Comment: After this JAR file appeared in `libs` but when I try to import some package I get message **The import androidplot cannot be resolved**.

Comment: Try building the project after you have imported jars